# qtips: how do I disable all tooltips on a page with a click function?

Tags: jquery, function, click, tooltip, qtip

I have written the following script to hide all qtip tooltips on my page and set a cookie using the jquery cookie plugin.  All works well except that only the tooltips that have been hovered over since page load are hidden/disabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide_tips").click( function() {
        $.cookie('qtip_hidden', true, { path: '/', expires: 10 });
        $('.qtip').qtip('disable');
    });
});
</script>
```

How do I get this to work with all tooltips on the page?

Thanks,

Nick

**Example of qTip script I am using**

```
$('.tooltip[title]').qtip({
position: {
    my: 'top left', 
    at: 'bottom center'
},
style: {
    classes: 'ui-tooltip-rounded ui-tooltip-light'
},
show: {
    effect: function() { $(this).fadeIn(500); } 
},
hide: {
    effect: function() { $(this).fadeOut(500); } 
}
});
```

Comment: @kleinohad I have added an example of a qTip script on my page.  Not sure if this is how I enable qTip though

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var MyQtips = $('.tooltip[title]').qtip({
position: {
    my: 'top left', 
    at: 'bottom center'
},
style: {
    classes: 'ui-tooltip-rounded ui-tooltip-light'
},
show: {
    effect: function() { $(this).fadeIn(500); } 
},
hide: {
    effect: function() { $(this).fadeOut(500); } 
}
});
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide_tips").click( function() {
        $.cookie('qtip_hidden', true, { path: '/', expires: 10 });
        $(MyQtips).qtip('disable'); //change
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately no qTips are hidden with this method, even ones previously hovered over

Comment: sorry try it now - look at the change

Comment: mmmh, same result i'm afraid. no tooltips are disabled.